# RESTful Web Services from Database error build-impl.xml

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8

I'm a beginner in Java EE development.

I try to make a REST web service using Netbeans 8.0.2 with a Glassfish Server 4.1 and a MySQL database which contains my tables.

So I create a new **Web Application**, then I create a new package in the folder **Sources Package** of the web application, and I create a new web service in that package, this web service is a **RESTful web services from database**.

In the **Services** tab, I click on **Databases**, then I register my MySQL server and I create a new connection to my database on my MySQL server, it works.

During the creation of the RESTful web service, it connects to my database.

But when I run my project, I have this error :

```
nbproject/build-impl.xml:1046: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED
```

I don't know how to resolve it.

The Glassfish server doesn't show log, I'm surprised because there isn't any log.

I go to the **Services** tab in Netbeans, and under **Servers** I right click on my Glassfish server and I click on **View Domain Server Log** but nothing occurs, so I open a command interface, and I go to the directory of the log of my Glassfish server and there is nothing

The tab which have the same name of my project shows this output :

```
NetBeansProjects\WebApplicationGlassfish2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1046: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 53 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of ideas in case you haven't check it.

If you are using the Glassfish server be sure the MySQL driver is installed on the server. You can check this in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html)

Second, it's not enough to configure the DB in your Netbeans, in your project you should create the proper configuration in your persistence.xml file (usually, unless your are using jdbc manually). You should create your datasource or, at least, register the connection properties.

I hope it helps.